# Get Posts by multiple custom fields is not working

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I have made two dropdown list which is a custom fields.

```
Custom Field 1 :- industry
```

Values of Custom Field 1 :- financial_services,ecommerce,insurances, etc.

```
Custom Field 2 :- primary_functionality
```

Values of Custom Field 2 :-
 `platform_decision_engine,user_authentication,data_provider_verification` etc.

And My Post Type Name is :- providers.

Now, I want to fetch posts with multiple custom fields.

So, I have tried this query. But it's not working. How to pass array in values field because it's give me unexpected result.

Even I tried with for single custom field but it's also not working.

```
$search_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'providers',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'orderby'       => 'title',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'industry',
                'value'     => $industry,
                'compare'   => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'primary_functionality',
                'value'     => array('platform_decision_engine'),
                'compare'   => 'IN'
            )
        ),
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );  
}
    $the_query_search = new WP_Query( $search_args );
```

This Query is not getting expected result.

EDIT :

```
[query] => Array
        (
            [posts_per_page] => -1
            [post_type] => providers
            [post_status] => publish
            [meta_query] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => industry
                            [value] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => ecommerce
                                )

                            [compare] => IN
                        )
                )    
        )
```

Getting this array but data is not according to ecommerce.

Add Field pic : [image]

Comment: What result did you get and what did you expect? "Not working" is kind of broad...

Comment: @cjbj i updated my code.

Comment: Can you share how your custom fields are defined? (code or plugin or something). To get a better idea.

Comment: @rozklad, i upload custom field list. it's a plugin (Custom Post Type UI).

Answer (score 0):

If you have array based values in custom fields defined by ACF (as i can see from your screenshot), you will want to write meta query with LIKE as compare instead of IN.

I'm assuming your "providers" post type looks something like this:
[image]

Here is your example written with LIKE compare:

```
<?php

    $search_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'providers',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'orderby'       => 'title',
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'industry',
                'value'     => 'financial_services',
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'primary_functionality',
                'value'     => 'platform_decision_engine',
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
        'suppress_filters' => true
    );  

    $the_query_search = new WP_Query( $search_args );

    while($the_query_search->have_posts()) : $the_query_search->the_post();

        echo get_the_title() . '<br>';

    endwhile;

?>
```

Refer to https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/ for more information on custom field meta queries.

Comment: thank you for a response, I try your code but the same issue.
Not getting proper data.

Comment: its difficult to tell whats the problem. i tested it on a clean wp installation http://se.rozklad.me/ with some testing providers set up as seen on the screenshot - fields industry and primary_functionality being type Checkbox and it returns results as expected.